# Easiest way to animate lots of objects in Qt

Tags: c++, qt, user-interface

I have lots of QLabels and need to animate them all. Like, move them outside the screen to hide them, and move them back. I could create one QPropertyAnimation to each one, but that doesn't sounds right.

I tried to make them all children from the same parent and then move the parent, but they actually don't show when I use a different parent then the main Window. (Feel free to help me with that also, but I think it looks like another question)

I hope I made my problem clear enough. Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you add them to a already visible widget, try updateGeometries() on the parent. Not knowing exactly what you aim for: Maybe QGraphicsView with text items is a better solution?

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way would be to use your "same parent" solution.

You should check that your parent widget is big enough to contain all the other labels and that its own parent is the main window.